# rewrite url with .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website and i'm linking like this:

```
a href="?lang=en&amp;p=3"
```

My url is like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/?lang=en&p=3
```

but I want my url the become like this:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/english/about-us
```

I know you got something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ ?lang=$1&p=$2
```

but it is not working...

Can somebody help me out with this `.htaccess` file?

And do I have to change my href url's aswell?

Thanks in advance!

Kind Regards

Comment: Are you using any CMS for that? You would need to forward your url to http://www.mywebsite.com/?lang=english&p=about-us and handle the rest with PHP so that the page with ID 3 will load.

Comment: Yes I'm using a CMS with it... so this has nothing to do with .htaccess? I can edit this in my CMS too? Is it possible to give an example of that?

Comment: what CMS you use? wordpress, i guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=([a-zA-Z]*)&p=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

This will make 301 redirect from:
http://www.mywebsite.com/?lang=en&p=3
to:
http://www.mywebsite.com/en/3

If you want some other rules for redirect, modify that rules for your needs, e.g. make list of such more specific `RewriteCond` with its rules.

Answer (score 1):

Use this with hard coded page names if your site requires parameters like p=3

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/about-us$ ./?lang=$1&p=3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/another-page$ ./?lang=$1&p=4 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If you modify your site so that it accepts parameters like p=about-us it gets simpler:

( http://www.mywebsite.com/?lang=en&p=about-us )

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ ./?lang=$1&p=$2 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If you don't change your href urls as well, it all makes no sense, as google will not see the plain text urls (nobody will) even if they work.

Comment: Thanks for your help:) I tried that and it worked but now my whole style is gone? and when I dont have a page yet (index) I need to use something like this? RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./?lang=$1 [QSA]

Comment: Adding the page like index.php would be probably safer, but ./ is the current directory, so it works even if you rename the page (if it is the default page for a directory, like default.asp index.php home.php, etc..) and I never found a server/browser that wouldn't work with it

Comment: About the style, the RewriteRule probably catches it, so you'll have to handle that. If Your style is in /css/style.css it will be translated to ./?lang=css&p=style.css. As a solution you could hard code language options like this: RewriteRule ^(en|it|de|ru)/(.*)$ ./?lang=$1&p=$2 [QSA] but be careful that they do not match other folders of your site. This way, "en" will be considered a language, while "css" will be considered a folder